# Questions about the definition of std::function class

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function

I saw its source code(Mac XCode, `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/functional`) is

```
template<class R, class... ArgTypes>                                                                                                            
class function<R(ArgTypes...)>
  : public unary_function<T1, R>      // iff sizeof...(ArgTypes) == 1 and
                                      // ArgTypes contains T1
  : public binary_function<T1, T2, R> // iff sizeof...(ArgTypes) == 2 and
                                      // ArgTypes contains T1 and T2
{...};
```

Here I have two questions for it:

1. Is it legal to have

   `class C : public A : public D {}`

? It seems illegal but the source code for std::function does compile. Why?

2. What does this

   `template<class A, B>
   class foo<A(B)> //Can we have "<A(B)>" here? What's its meaning?
   {...}`

mean? As an old man who's only familiar with C++98 I don't understand  `class foo<A(B)>`, and I thought a type parameter list `<...>` could only appear after the `template` for a template definition. BTW, I know `A(B)` can be a function type.

---

Update 1:
Thanks for @Chris Drew who points out the code snippet of question 1 is from within a (big) comment so it's a kind of pseudocode. Please forget it. So question one is gone. But question two is still there.

---

Update 2:
I mean this

`class foo<A(B)> //Can we have "<A(B)>" here? What's its meaning?`

not

`class foo<A(B)> //Can we have "<...>" here? What's its meaning?`

The above `<...>` is really a short cut for `<A(B)>`. I'm sorry for the misleading.

I think if `A(B)` is effectively a function type, then it should be

```
template<F>
class foo {...}
```

where `F` is `A(B)`, according to my C++98 knowledge, and

```
template<class A, B>
class foo<A(B)>
{...}
```

seems not right.

Comment: You are referring to libc++ code right? And I believe [the code you have found](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/functional) is within a comment block and is effectively pseudocode.

Comment: that time when we had to debug comments...

Comment: @ChrisDrew OMG! It is! Thank you. But still, I have the 2nd question.

Comment: once cleaned this question tantamounts to "what is a class template partial specialization ?", mark as duplicate ?

Comment: There are loads of questions about partial specializations, and several about how `std::function` encodes the return and argument types as `A(B)`

Comment: @JonathanWakely But the key point is: how did I know it's a question on partial specialization? If I'd knew it then I would not have the question.

Comment: It's still a duplicate though. And btw, the syntax is pure C++98, there's nothing C++11 about it (except that `std::function` is from C++11, but it can be implemented in pure C++98, see Boost.Function)

Comment: @JonathanWakely OK, I'd like to say I'm not an C++ expert like you're. That's why I had the question. Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As an old man who's only familiar with C++98 I don't understand class foo, and I thought a type parameter list <...> could only appear after the template for a template definition. BTW, I know A(B) can be a function type.

that's the syntax of a *class template partial specialization*:

```
template<class T> struct A {}; // primary class template declaration
template<class Whatever1,class Whatever2> struct A< /*whatever*/ > {}; // class template partial specialization
```

where `/*whatever*/` is the template argument list relative to the primary class template declaration used for matching it.

In other words, whenever your class template `A` is instantiated with some arguments `T1,...`, the compiler considers both `A`'s primary definition and all its visible partial specializations `A<something>`, trying to match 'T1,...' to 'something' according to function template deduction rules. If no macthes are found the primary def is used; otherwise, the best matching candidate is used ( if unique ).

Answer (score 1):

1) it is a syntax error, `:` should only appear before first item in base classes list, then `,` should be used:

```
template<class R, class... ArgTypes>
class function<R(ArgTypes...)>
:   public unary_function<T1, R>    // iff sizeof...(ArgTypes) == 1 and
                                    // ArgTypes contains T1
,   public binary_function<T1, T2, R>
```

Actually it is more like the code snippet you've posted in incomplete.

2) it is a template parameters pack for a `function` template class specialization

```
template<typename TSome, typename TOther> class
t_Foo{ ... };

// specialization for cases when TSome is the same as TOther
template<typename T> class
t_Foo<T, T>{ ... }; // now we have <...> after template keyword and after template name as well
```

Comment: For 1) The source code does compile. I've updated my question and pointed out the exact path for the source code. For 2), I know what a parameters pack mean, but my question is for `class foo<A(B)>`.

Comment: @Robert See my comment on your question. The "code" you posted is from a `/* functional synopsis ... */` section and is just a comment.

Comment: @Robert: And how the comment in the comment is realized in real code is part of my answer...

Answer (score 1):

> Is it legal to have `class C : public A : public D {}`

Never seen that before and gcc did not compile it. To have, as seen in the
comments of the code you posted, if conditions in compilation, SFINAE or simply an overload is used. The implementation on gcc is something like:

```
  template<typename _Res, typename... _ArgTypes>
    class function<_Res(_ArgTypes...)>
    : public _Maybe_unary_or_binary_function<_Res, _ArgTypes...>
      ... code continues here ...
```

where _Maybe_unary_or_binary_function is overload like this:

```
  /**
   * Derives from @c unary_function or @c binary_function, or perhaps
   * nothing, depending on the number of arguments provided. The
   * primary template is the basis case, which derives nothing.
   */
  template<typename _Res, typename... _ArgTypes>
    struct _Maybe_unary_or_binary_function { };

  /// Derives from @c unary_function, as appropriate.
  template<typename _Res, typename _T1>
    struct _Maybe_unary_or_binary_function<_Res, _T1>
    : std::unary_function<_T1, _Res> { };

  /// Derives from @c binary_function, as appropriate.
  template<typename _Res, typename _T1, typename _T2>
    struct _Maybe_unary_or_binary_function<_Res, _T1, _T2>
    : std::binary_function<_T1, _T2, _Res> { };
```

> What does this

```
template<class A, B>
class foo<A(B)> //Can we have "<...>" here? What's its meaning?
{...}
```

It is commonly used if you want to write your template instantiation with the function syntax like:

```
foo< void( int ) > f;
```

And yes, you can use `...`at any place:

```
template <typename RETVAL, typename ... PARMS>
class Func<RETVAL(PARMS...)>
{
};

int main()
{
    Func<void(int, float)> f;
    Func<int()> f1;
    Func<float( std::string )> f2;
}
```

Update:

> I think if A(B) is effectively a function type, then it should be

```
template<F>
class foo {...}
```

It is not the `function type` itself, it is simply a way / syntax to use the function syntax to define the parameters of the template. If you would use `F` as something like the function type, you can make it a template template. But that will not help for anything, because inside the class which will use that type, you must get access to each parameter of the definition. If you only have a `F` here, you only can forward this `F` to another template, because you can not access the return value and parameters of `F` inside you template class itself. So what is it good for?

UPDATE:

If you want to implement a template which takes a template as parameter which itself takes an function argument you can do it. I list you all the variants from normal template, template template and all this also with the function type. Hope that helps:
    // define a standard template class
    template 
    class Templ{};

```
// define one with template template parameter
template < template <typename> class TEMPL >
class TemplTempl {};

// and now to catch a function type
template <typename RETVAL, typename ... PARMS> class Func;

template <typename RETVAL, typename ... PARMS>
class Func<RETVAL(PARMS...)>
{
    public:
        static void Do() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
};

// and how to define a template which takes a template which takes a function type parameter?
template < template < typename RETVAL, typename ... PARMS > class F>
class FuncTempl{};

template < template < typename , typename ... > class F, typename RETVAL, typename ... PARMS >
class FuncTemplUser
{
    static void Do() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
};

template < template < typename , typename ... > class F, typename RETVAL, typename ... PARMS >
class FuncTemplUser< F, RETVAL(PARMS...)> : public F<RETVAL(PARMS...)>
{
    public:
    static void Do() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; F<RETVAL(PARMS...)>::Do(); }
};



int main()
{
    // using the standard templates
    Templ<int> n1;
    // and the template which takes a template as parm
    TemplTempl<Templ> n2;

    // now use one with function type
    Func<void(int, float)> f;
    Func<void(int, float)>::Do();

    FuncTempl<Func> f2;

    FuncTemplUser<Func, void(int)> f3;
    f3.Do();
}
```

As you can see `FuncTempl` is taking a template which itself later can use the function type. That is exactly what you think your `F` will be.

Comment: @Robert: Updated my answer.. and if you want thank me, use the upvote button ;)

Comment: I know the purpose but I have question on the grammar. If we want only the declared type parameters then `template <class A, class B> foo {...}` is enough. And if we want a function pointer type like `A(B)`, we could do it by `using F = A(B)` inside the template class body. So what does `template <class A, class B> foo<A(B)> {...}` mean?

Comment: @Robert: Updated again. Now you have variants for templates which taking function types and also a template which takes a template which takes a function type which is hopefully what your question belongs to.